# Pandas DataFrame Calculations

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a fairly complex dataframe that looks like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0': {('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '24hr'): 6,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um',  '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control',  '24hr'): 6},
  '1': {('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '24hr'): 6,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um',  '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control',  '24hr'): 6},
  '2': {('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '24hr'): 6,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um',  '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control',  '24hr'): 6}})

print(df)
                                                 0   1   2
        Total Number of End Points 0.01um  0hr   12  12  12
                                           24hr  18  18  18
                                   0.1um   0hr    8   8   8
                                           24hr  12  12  12
                                   Control 0hr    4   4   4
                                           24hr   6   6   6
        Total Vessel Length        0.01um  0hr   12  12  12
                                           24hr  18  18  18
                                   0.1um   0hr    8   8   8
                                           24hr  12  12  12
                                   Control 0hr    4   4   4
                                           24hr   6   6   6
```

I'm trying to divide each value by the average of the columns in the corresponding control level.  I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
df2 = df.divide(df.xs('Control', level=1).mean(axis=1), axis='index')
```

I'm pretty new to python and pandas so I tend to think in MS Excel terms on this problem.

If it were in Excel the formula for A1 ('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '0hr', 0) would look be :

`=A1 / AVERAGE($A$5:$C$5)`

B1 ('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '0hr', 1) would be :

`=B1 / AVERAGE($A$5:$C$5)`

and A2 ('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '24hr', 0) would be

`=A1 / AVERAGE($A$6:$C$6)`

The desired result of this example would be :

```
                                                 0  1  2
        Total Number of End Points 0.01um  0hr   3  3  3
                                           24hr  3  3  3
                                   0.1um   0hr   2  2  2
                                           24hr  2  2  2
                                   Control 0hr   1  1  1
                                           24hr  1  1  1
        Total Vessel Length        0.01um  0hr   3  3  3
                                           24hr  3  3  3
                                   0.1um   0hr   2  2  2
                                           24hr  2  2  2
                                   Control 0hr   1  1  1
                                           24hr  1  1  1
```

Note : There are many indexes and columns in the real data.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: When I put you data, at the top of your question into a DataFrame it differs from what you get with print(df). The df=... and the print(df) are two different DataFrames. Your print(df) is unrelated to the code above. Your input columns as ['a', 'b'], but your printed columns are [0, 1, 2]. Can you make it all consistent. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkGraph Whoops .. you're correct .. I'll fix it.

Comment: In Pandas the data is organized internally by columns, and so it is easiest to extract or calculate a column. Could you perhaps reorganize the data so that all the control values are in their own column?

Answer (score 1):

It helps to have the `Control` values in their own columns. You can do that using `unstack`:

```
df.index.names = ['field', 'type', 'time']
df2 = df.unstack(['type']).swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)

# type                            0.01um 0.1um Control 0.01um 0.1um Control  \
#                                      0     0       0      1     1       1   
# field                      time                                             
# Total Number of End Points 0hr      12     8       4     12     8       4   
#                            24hr     18    12       6     18    12       6   
# Total Vessel Length        0hr      12     8       4     12     8       4   
#                            24hr     18    12       6     18    12       6   

# type                            0.01um 0.1um Control  
#                                      2     2       2  
# field                      time                       
# Total Number of End Points 0hr      12     8       4  
#                            24hr     18    12       6  
# Total Vessel Length        0hr      12     8       4  
#                            24hr     18    12       6
```

Now find the average of each Control:

```
ave = df2['Control'].mean(axis=1)
# field                       time
# Total Number of End Points  0hr     4
#                             24hr    6
# Total Vessel Length         0hr     4
#                             24hr    6
# dtype: float64
```

As you expected, you can use `df2.divide` to compute the desired result. Be sure to use `axis=0` to tell Pandas to match values (in `df2` and `ave`) based on the row index.

```
result = df2.divide(ave, axis=0)
# type                            0.01um 0.1um Control 0.01um 0.1um Control  \
#                                      0     0       0      1     1       1   
# field                      time                                             
# Total Number of End Points 0hr       3     2       1      3     2       1   
#                            24hr      3     2       1      3     2       1   
# Total Vessel Length        0hr       3     2       1      3     2       1   
#                            24hr      3     2       1      3     2       1   

# type                            0.01um 0.1um Control  
#                                      2     2       2  
# field                      time                       
# Total Number of End Points 0hr       3     2       1  
#                            24hr      3     2       1  
# Total Vessel Length        0hr       3     2       1  
#                            24hr      3     2       1
```

There are essentially the values that you are after. However, if you want to rearrange the DataFrame to look exactly as you posted, then:

```
result = result.stack(['type'])
result = result.reorder_levels(['field','type','time'], axis=0)
result = result.reindex(df.index)
```

yields

```
                                         0  1  2
field                      type    time         
Total Number of End Points 0.01um  0hr   3  3  3
                                   24hr  3  3  3
                           0.1um   0hr   2  2  2
                                   24hr  2  2  2
                           Control 0hr   1  1  1
                                   24hr  1  1  1
Total Vessel Length        0.01um  0hr   3  3  3
                                   24hr  3  3  3
                           0.1um   0hr   2  2  2
                                   24hr  2  2  2
                           Control 0hr   1  1  1
                                   24hr  1  1  1
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
df.index.names = ['field', 'type', 'time']
df2 = df.unstack(['type']).swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
ave = df2['Control'].mean(axis=1)
result = df2.divide(ave, axis=0)
result = result.stack(['type'])
result = result.reorder_levels(['field','type','time'], axis=0)
result = result.reindex(df.index)
```

Comment: Interesting.  I hadn't noticed that indexes could be tuples and had all these associated methods.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that pandas is organized to easily calculate over columns, and the question requires an average over a row to be deducted from other rows. Pandas isn't designed to work that way.

However, you can easily switch rows and columns with the transpose `.T`, and then it may be more tractable, and in fact the control mean is a one liner.

```
>>> df.T[(u'Total Vessel Length', u'Control', u'0hr')].mean()
4.0
```

This 4.0 comes from two 4.0 values in the original data:

```
>>> df.T[(u'Total Vessel Length', u'Control', u'0hr')]
a    4
b    4
```

At this point it looks like for loops will take care of the issue.

Untested:

```
for primary in (u'Total Vessel Length',u'Total Number of End Points'):
     for um in (u'0.01um',u'0.1um'):
         for hours in (u'0hr',u'24hr'):
             df.T[(primary,um,hours)]=df.T[(primary,um,hours)]/df.T[(primary, u'Control', hours)].mean()
```

Note that this doesn't divide the non-control columns, but it is easy to include 'control' into the um loop.

**UPDATE** That doesn't work, somehow it is not modifying the dataframe in place.  Right now, I'm not sure why.

But you can construct a new data frame by calling pd.DataFrame on a dict
comprehension.

This seems to be working...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'0': {('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '24hr'): 6,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um',  '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control',  '24hr'): 6},
  '1': {('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '24hr'): 6,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um',  '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control',  '24hr'): 6},
  '2': {('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Number of End Points', '0.1um', '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Number of End Points', 'Control', '24hr'): 6,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '0hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um', '0hr'): 8,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control', '0hr'): 4,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.01um', '24hr'): 18,
  ('Total Vessel Length', '0.1um',  '24hr'): 12,
  ('Total Vessel Length', 'Control',  '24hr'): 6}})

print df

df2 = pd.DataFrame({(primary,um,hours):df.T[(primary,um,hours)]/df.T[(primary,u'Control',hours)].mean() for primary in (u'Total Vessel Length',u'Total Number of End Points') for um in (u'0.01um',u'0.1um') for hours in (u'0hr',u'24hr')})

print df2.T
```

**OUTPUT**

```
paul@home:~/SO$ python ./r.py 
                                              0   1   2
(Total Number of End Points, 0.01um, 0hr)    12  12  12
(Total Number of End Points, 0.01um, 24hr)   18  18  18
(Total Number of End Points, 0.1um, 0hr)      8   8   8
(Total Number of End Points, 0.1um, 24hr)    12  12  12
(Total Number of End Points, Control, 0hr)    4   4   4
(Total Number of End Points, Control, 24hr)   6   6   6
(Total Vessel Length, 0.01um, 0hr)           12  12  12
(Total Vessel Length, 0.01um, 24hr)          18  18  18
(Total Vessel Length, 0.1um, 0hr)             8   8   8
(Total Vessel Length, 0.1um, 24hr)           12  12  12
(Total Vessel Length, Control, 0hr)           4   4   4
(Total Vessel Length, Control, 24hr)          6   6   6

[12 rows x 3 columns]
                                            0  1  2
(Total Number of End Points, 0.01um, 0hr)   3  3  3
(Total Number of End Points, 0.01um, 24hr)  3  3  3
(Total Number of End Points, 0.1um, 0hr)    2  2  2
(Total Number of End Points, 0.1um, 24hr)   2  2  2
(Total Vessel Length, 0.01um, 0hr)          3  3  3
(Total Vessel Length, 0.01um, 24hr)         3  3  3
(Total Vessel Length, 0.1um, 0hr)           2  2  2
(Total Vessel Length, 0.1um, 24hr)          2  2  2

[8 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result out as in.  Is there an `inplace=True` needed somewhere?

Comment: Same gotcha here.  Seems eerily familiar.  I'll look around.

Comment: maybe related.  still looking.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995328/changing-values-in-pandas-dataframe-doenst-work