# How to change the column value depends on other column in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change the value of one column based on some other column value. Can you please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
table                sql                                                  object_type
VW_MDCL_INSIGT       select * from MEDAFF_REF_SPECTRUM.MEDICAL_INSIGHT    VIEW
TBL_MDCL_INSIGT      select * from medaff_ref_spectrum.CALL
FBMS_INTERACTION     select * from medaff_ref_spectrum.TERR
VW_FBMS_INTERACTIONS select * from MEDAFF_REF_SPECTRUM.FBMS_INTERACTIONS  VIEW
```

Expected Output:

```
table                sql                                                            object_type
VW_MDCL_INSIGT       create or replace VW_MDCL_INSIGT as select * from MEDAFF_REF_SPECTRUM.MEDICAL_INSIGHT              VIEW
TBL_MDCL_INSIGT      select * from medaff_ref_spectrum.CALL
FBMS_INTERACTION     select * from medaff_ref_spectrum.TERR
VW_FBMS_INTERACTIONS create or replace VW_FBMS_INTERACTIONS as select * from MEDAFF_REF_SPECTRUM.FBMS_INTERACTIONS      VIEW
```

whenever object_type = VIEW, just add `create or replace+ table+ as` in sql.

I tried below code. Can you please suggest me what am i doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd 
import csv


df = pd.read_csv("D:/Users/SPate233/Downloads/iMedical/sqoop/metadata_consump.txt", delimiter='|')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if(row['object_type'] == 'VIEW'):
        row['sql'] = 'create or replace '+row['tablename']+' as '+row['sql']

print(df['sql'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your solution wasn't working it's because you were modifying a copy of the row of the dataframe, see this [helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17996532/13676202) about setting a new value of the dataframe while looping. You could try with `np.where` better:

```
df['sql']=np.where(df.object_type.eq('VIEW'), 'create or replace'+' '+df.table+' '+df.sql, df.sql)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                  table                                                sql object_type
0        VW_MDCL_INSIGT  create or replace VW_MDCL_INSIGT select * from...        VIEW
1       TBL_MDCL_INSIGT             select * from medaff_ref_spectrum.CALL            
2      FBMS_INTERACTION             select * from medaff_ref_spectrum.TERR            
3  VW_FBMS_INTERACTIONS  create or replace VW_FBMS_INTERACTIONS select ...        VIEW
```

Comment: You're welcome, just added a helpful link, about the setting of values while looping. I suggest you to see it, and maybe modify your original answer, if you want to keep it.  Also, I'll appreciate if you upvote the answer :)!